# How to implement this UI using QT?

Tags: qt, coordinates

How to implement this UI using QT?

1) There are values in the x, y axis. 
2) we can move vertical and horizontal scroll-bars. And the x, y values will change
3) when mouse move to a pointer, its (x,y) values will be shown.

is there any examples I can study to achieve this UI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[QCusomplot download](http://www.qcustomplot.com/index.php/download)  A Thirdparty library will be useul to solve your problem, but it has many featues too. extracting your requirement code is bit challanging. QCustomPlot is derived from QWidget, with pixmap rendering effectively. So it is fast.  default license is GPL too.